# Where Linq Method returning elements that don't satisfy condition

Tags: linq, conditional-statements, where-clause

I am invoking Where method on a List and is returning elements that don't satisfy my condition.

Here is my call to the Where method:

```
IEnumerable<MyObject> list = returnList.Where(p => p.MaxDate != null && p.MinDate != null);
```

I am expecting to have on "list" IEnumerable only the objects that have both MaxDate and MinDate defined (not null)!

And "list" ends with the same results as my returnList, and actually none of the items on "list" as the MaxDate and MinDate defined (different than null), my where condition was supposed to return no elements in that case, am I right?

Thank you very much in advance

EDIT2 (I added the namespaces I am using, maybe there is some bug with this):

Simple example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        class MyObject
        {
            public DateTime? MinDate { get; set; }
            public DateTime? MaxDate { get; set; }
            public string Description{ get; set; }

        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<MyObject> lista = new List<MyObject>();
            lista.Add(new MyObject { Description = "123" });
            lista.Add(new MyObject { Description = "456" });
            lista.Add(new MyObject { Description = "678" });

            IEnumerable<MyObject> returnn = lista.Where(p => p.MinDate != null && p.MaxDate != null); //this list contains 3 elements and should have 0!! Microsoft bug???? I can't understand this!
        }
}
```

Comment: It's very hard to tell what's wrong without a way of reproducing the problem. Please include a [mcve] in your question - it sohuld be fine.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question now ;)

Comment: Zero items here with your code.

Comment: What the hell? seriously?? What is wrong with my machine??

Comment: Any constructor initialization in your real "MyObject"?

Comment: I am not using any constructor as you see in my code, I edited my question adding the namespaces, do you have the same as me? thanks ;)

Comment: How are you confirming that `returnn` is not empty? What does this do if you put it *after* the Where line? `Console.WriteLine("Items in returnn: " + returnn.ToList().Count);`

Comment: Thanks mate, I was checking the wrong attribute (source of IEnumerable) in debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jesus, I am feeling so dumb right now, I was looking at the field "source" in the IEnumerable attribute "returnn", instead of checking the actual ResultsView, I made a ToList() and returned no elements!

I am so sorry lol, maybe someone can close this question...

Thank you all for the efforts everyone! The problem was in front of the computer (me) LOL

Answer (score 1):

```
returnList.Where(p => p.MaxDate.HasValue && p.MinDate.HasValue);
```

Working example: 
https://dotnetfiddle.net/qQrjkC

Edit: even the `!= null` should also work, you should do your tests properly before giving downvotes

Comment: tryed right now, still returning 3 elements, can't figured this out :O

Comment: @DarkLink  So what IS the value? If it claims to have a value.... find out what it is. Perhaps they are defaulting somehow?

Make a foreach, and lookat your values in intellisense

Comment: I didn't give downvotes mate, it wasn't me, I figured it out the problem, thank you so much for your effort, I will give you a upvote right now ;)